# Многое перепробовал, но объект так и не хранит массивы, после их заполнения

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети, vector, конструктор, векторы

Решил создать нейронную сеть с нуля...

[Код](https://replit.com/@79055791490/Neuronet#Neuron.h)

Или тут:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
typedef unsigned int uint;
class Neuron {
public:
  int countInput = 0;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> input;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> weight;
  double output = 0;

  Neuron() {}
  Neuron(std::vector<std::vector<double>>&);


  double result();
};


Neuron::Neuron(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& inp) {
  srand(time(0));
  this->countInput = (int)inp[0].size();
  for (uint i = 0; i < countInput; i++) {
    input.push_back(std::vector<double>());
    weight.push_back(std::vector<double>());
    for (uint j = 0; j < countInput; j++) {
      input[i].push_back(inp[i][j]);
      weight[i].push_back(0.5);
    }
  }
}
double Neuron::result() {
  output = 0;
  std::cout << this->input.size();
  for (uint i = 0; i < countInput; i++) {
    for (uint j = 0; j < countInput; i++) {
      output += input[i][j] * weight[i][j];
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что значит "не хранит"? Как вы проверяете/убеждаетесь?

Но в любом случае - зачем вообще все эти сложности? Почему бы не написать просто

```
Neuron::Neuron(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& inp)
    :input(inp), weight(inp.size(),vector<double>(inp[0].size(),0.5)){}
```

Еще у вас есть ошибка и непонятка...

Ошибка - в цикле

```
for (uint j = 0; j < countInput; i++)
```

проверяете `j`, а увеличиваете `i` и пытаетесь потом работать с несуществующим вектором... Видимо, происходящий при этом этот слет программы вы и называете "не хранит массивы"?

Непонятка - зачем вызывать `srand` в конструкторе? Критично, чтобы после каждого нового объекта последовательность случайных чисел повторялась (вряд ли время за секунду успеет за это время перескочить...)?

Comment: С циклом, не заметил, спасибо...

С `srand`, просто пока не убрал.

А "не заполнялись" массивы, потому что `net` уже имел 10 элементов(в main.cpp):
```std::vector<Neuron> net(10);
  double sum = 0;
  for (uint i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    net.push_back(Neuron(image));
    sum += net[i].result();
  }```

Comment: Так, простите, какого черты вы даете не тот код?... Знаете такое требование к вопросу - *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*?

Comment: Эмм... Я сейчас только заметил, что в самом вопросе, нет части с `main.cpp`...
Я думал, что вставлял его... Если это не ошибка сервера, а моя или моей слабой сети - прошу прощения, что не доглядел.